# Cannot run auctex on emacs

Tags: emacs, auctex

I installed `auctex` via `M-x package-install`. I then added this line to my `.emacs` file: `(require 'auctex)`. However, upon startup, Emacs complains that `` error: Required feature `auctex' was not provided ``. When I run in debug mode, I get the following:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Required feature `auctex' was not provided")
  require(auctex)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/koz/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer      position 2277
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/koz/.emacs" "/home/koz/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
```

I suspect I missed something that I should have added to my `.emacs` file, but I'm not sure what it is. Could someone help me out?

Comment: (require 'tex) instead of auctex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library that needs to be loaded is called `tex` rather than `auctex`.  Therefore, the following line of code is used instead of `(require 'auctex)`:

```
(require 'tex)
```